# Width/Height not changing in SB when changing size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode8

I just updated to xcode 8 and I am having problems when I change size classes.

In this simple example I have a mapview that should take up the entire space in a view.  I constrained left/right and top/bottom and am looking at iPhone SE.

[image]

However if I click the iPhone 6 Plus view the width/height do not change and I get constraint warnings. As the constraints expect the view to take up the entire space and they do not.

[image]

I created a brand new project with this same simple example and the mapview will change in width/height as you change the size classes as you would expect.  This is what I see in apples videos on xcode 8 and stoyboarding and what they claim works.

This leaves me with what is wrong with my storyboard and why is this not working?  Do I need to do anything to make sure my storyboard is converted properly from xcode 7 to xcode 8?  I have set the storyboard to open in 'Latest Xcode (8.0)' which did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may very well be a bug in IB.  I have switched the size cases back an forth in a simple case and it sometimes screws up.  Wish there was a way to force IB to retry.